# Granting application users access to Amazon S3 but hitting 5000 user limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

1. Create users dynamicly through API(users might grow alot - 50-100k+ eventually)
2. Give those users access to a specific prefix of an AWS S3 bucket(IAM policy)

Currently my idea is to create AWS IAM Users and generate credentials for those users(The credentials should not be temporary). This works fine, but the problem is that AWS is limited to 5000 IAM users. Is there another way to avoid that limit. One way that I found out is via cognito users -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html
However I do not think that there is a way to create long-term access keys(as the IAM user access keys) for those cognito users ?

Is there another way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you need permanent access keys for this many users?

Comment: Because I do not want the user to reauthenticate in order to get new access keys, because the app runs 24/7.

Comment: AWS sessions also expire and need to be re-authenticated, also issues like MFA and the fact that users need to keep those keys somewhere will also arise. IAM users aren't really suited for this.

Comment: I think you are trying to use AWS IAM to manage your users but you are looking for an application level IAM solution like Okta, ForgeRock, Ping Identity, etc. I would encourage you to instead re-look at your architecture if you expect your users count to grow that large. IMO, it would be worth the investment. And once you have that solution in place then the above issue will be no issue.

Comment: IAM users is definitely the wrong approach here. You need to investigate federated identity solutions or AWS Single Sign On, and leverage IAM roles that authenticated users can assume to give them temporary STS credentials.

Comment: Yes, but I want to avoid the temporary credentials, thats why it works with IAM users

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** use IAM for application users. IAM is for staff within your organisation to operate your AWS infrastructure.

Your application should **operate its own authentication method separate from IAM** (as suggested in the above comments). An example of using AWS for this task would be to use Amazon Cognito.

Once a user has authenticated, you have a couple of options:

**Option 1: Using AWS credentials**

If you want to allow the authenticated users to access AWS resources (eg Amazon S3) via AWS API calls, then you can create temporary credentials that have limited permissions (eg can access any object within a given path of a given bucket). These credentials can then be provided to the users. This method is commonly used for mobile applications that are capable of making API calls directly to AWS. It requires that the users have software that can *use* the AWS credentials.

**Option 2: Amazon S3 pre-signed URLS**

If you are running a web application and you want users to be able to access private objects in Amazon S3, you can generate pre-signed URLs. For example, let's say you are running a photo-sharing website. The process would be:

- Photos are kept in private S3 buckets.
- Users **authenticate** to the application.
- The application can then show them their private photos: When the application generates any links to this private content, or embeds content in the page (eg via `<img>` tags), it generates a **pre-signed URL**, which provides time-limited access to private content.
- The user then **accesses** the URL, or their browser requests data (eg images) from that URL.
- Amazon S3 **verifies the signature** on the URL and check the validity time. If it is correct, then S3 returns the private object.

The application uses a set of IAM credentials to *sign* the pre-signed URL. This can be done in a couple of lines of code and does not require an API call to AWS.

The benefit of this method is that the *application* is responsible for determining which objects the user may access. For example, let's say a user wants to share their photos with another user. This sharing information can be stored in a database and the application can consult the database when sharing photos. If a user is entitled to view another user's photos, the application can generate a pre-signed URL without caring in which directory the photos are stored. This is a **much more flexible approach** than using storage location to grant access. However, it does require **additional logic within the application.**

See: [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Comment: Hi, just to clarify are your two options referring to when you are using Amazon Cognito.

Comment: @Epirocks The above options are not directly using Amazon Cognito. They both assume that the application has already authenticated the user. The authentication might have used Amazon Cognito, or some other method (eg credentials stored in a database).

Comment: Thanks. The irritating thing for me is the fact they only have Android/iOS/Web App library. But I want it in C# I want to upload a folder structure rather than a few images so want to push them up using C# or Powershell. I am pondering to try and present the Web App with a .NET Webview2 and extracting the token that is returned and then sending it to a powershell script. Not sure if I'll be bitten in the ass somewhere along.